# itemize shortcut environment in emacs

Tags: emacs, shortcut

I know that M-RET creates a `\item` in emacs (latex mode) even if there is no `\begin{itemize}` `\end{itemize}` around.

In the case we are not within such environment I am wondering if it is possible to create it first and then put the `\item` in the middle. So after a first M-Ret we would get :

```
\begin{itemize}
\item
\end{itemize}
```

and after a second M-RET

```
\begin{itemize}
\item
\item 
\end{itemize}
```

I am using `itemize` because it is the one I use the most but I guess this could be changed if required.

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. This Question better goes in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes : I have posted it on : https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69517/itemize-shortcut-environment-in-emacs